# How to prevent Vim indenting wrapped text in parentheses

Tags: vim, latex, indentation, word-wrap

This has bugged me for a long time, and try as I might I can't find a way round it.

When I'm editing text (specifically latex, but that doesn't matter) files, I want it to auto-wrap at 80 columns. It does this, except if I happen to be in the middle of a parenthetical clause, it indents the text which is *very* annoying. For example, this works fine

```
Here is some text... over
two lines.
```

but this doesn't

```
Here is some text... (over
                      two
                      lines
```

If anyone can tell me how to turn this off (just for text/latex files) I'd be really grateful. Presumably it has something to do with the fact that this is desired behaviour in C, but I still can't figure out what's wrong.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
:set nocindent
```

The other options do nothing, and the filetype detection doesn't change it.

Comment: After doing so, most people probably would want to follow that up with `:set smartindent`, to still indent to your designated `shiftwidth` (e.g., one tab to the right of the start of the line above) -- which can be made permanent for C type files by putting `let b:did_indent = 1` (to prevent `cindent` from being set) followed by `setlocal smartindent` in `~/.vim/indent/c.vim`.

Answer (score 5):

There are three options you may need to turn off: set noai, set nosi, and setnocin (autoindent, smartindent, and cindent).

Answer (score 4):

This may be related, when pasting from gui into terminal window, vim cannot distinguish paste modes, so to stop any odd things from occuring:

```
set paste
```

then paste text

```
set nopaste
```

I had similar issues trying to paste xml text, it would just keep indenting. :)

**gvim**, the gui version of vim, can detect paste modes.

Comment: for booleans use a ! to toggle. that way you can use the command history: :set paste! <then paste> :<up-arrow>

Answer (score 3):

You can have a look at the autoindent option :

> autoindent - ai
>
> Copy indent from current line when starting a new line (typing 
>       in Insert mode or when using the "o" or "O" command).  If you do not
>       type anything on the new line except  and then type  or
>       , the indent is deleted again.  When autoindent is on,
>       formatting (with the "gq" command or when you reach 'textwidth' in
>       Insert mode) uses the indentation of the first line.   When
>       'smartindent' or 'cindent' is on the indent is changed in specific
>       cases.  The 'autoindent' option is reset when the 'paste' option is
>       set.  {small difference from Vi: After the indent is deleted when
>       typing  or , the cursor position when moving up or down is
>       after the deleted indent; Vi puts the cursor somewhere in the deleted
>       indent}.

Comment: Ah. cindent appears to be the culprit. I'd tried autoindent and smartindent but they made no difference.

What's the best way to set this for text/latex files?

Comment: look at my other answer, i think you'll have the solution with filetype indent.

Answer (score 2):

From the official [Vim documentation](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/usr_05.html)

> filetype plugin indent on
>
> This switches on three very clever
> mechanisms:
>
> 1. Filetype detection.    Whenever you start editing a file, Vim will try to
>    figure out what kind of    file this
>    is.  When you edit "main.c", Vim will
>    see the ".c" extension and
>    recognize this as a "c" filetype.
>    When you edit a file that starts with
>    "#!/bin/sh", Vim will recognize it as
>    a "sh" filetype.    The filetype
>    detection is used for syntax
>    highlighting and the other two
>    items below.    See |filetypes|.
> 2. Using filetype plugin files    Many different filetypes are edited with
>    different options.  For example,
>    when you edit a "c" file, it's very
>    useful to set the 'cindent' option to
>    automatically indent the lines.  These
>    commonly useful option settings are
>    included with Vim in filetype plugins.
>    You can also add your own, see
>    |write-filetype-plugin|.
> 3. Using indent files    When editing programs, the indent of a line can
>    often be computed    automatically.
>    Vim comes with these indent rules for
>    a number of    filetypes.  See
>    |:filetype-indent-on| and
>    'indentexpr'.

Comment: I think you should try to look for a filetype-plugin wrote by someone with the same problem for latex files, or maybe you could try to write one.

Comment: ah, ok. I'll take a look at the latex one and see if it's easy to modify

Answer (score 1):

:set noai

sets no auto indent tt may be smartindent though. Check out the doc and see if you can find something more

http://www.vim.org/htmldoc/indent.html

Comment: Funny, this was the only one that worked for me, `:set nocindent` did nothing in my case.